# Fill element with value in a json

Tags: javascript, json

I have this type of json:

```
{
    "datas": [
        {
            "id": "fruit_name",
            "value": "Banana"
        },
        {
            "id": "fruit_description",
            "value": "This is a banana."
        },
        ...
```

How can I autocomplete the following html with their value ?

```
<div id="fruit_name"></div>
<div id="fruit_description"></div>
```

I already tried:

```
function createElements() {
    // Parse JSON response.
    var elements = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

    elements.datas.forEach(function (element) {
        var div = document.getElementById(element.id);
        div.innerHTML = element.value;
    });
}

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();    
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState === 4) {
        createElements();
    }
}
request.responseType = "json";
request.open("GET", "datas.json", true);
request.send();
```

But it does not work and I have this error:

```
[Error] InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.
    createElements (index.html, line 20)
    onreadystatechange (index.html, line 31)
```

Anyone for help me with this please ?

Thanks.

Comment: in `createElements` are you sure `request` is accessible and in scope ? Try debugging.

Comment: In the `onreadystatechange` run `createElements(request);`

Comment: @vihan1086: makes the same...

Comment: @teamo Ah, do what I said in the previous commend. Then in your function, make it `function createElements(request) {`

Comment: @vihan1086: I made what you said but the same...

Comment: @teamo updated my answer, that should work for sure. type `json` is not valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request` is probably not defined *(in scope)* in your function. Either you can call it and use `this` or of the following

```
function createElements(request) {//Get the 'request' passed.
    // Parse JSON response.
    var elements = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

    elements.datas.forEach(function (element) {
        var div = document.getElementById(element.id);
        div.innerHTML = element.value;
    });
}

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();    
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState === 4) {
        createElements(request);//Pass in 'request'
    }
}

request.responseType = "application/json";//Remove line if there are errors
request.open("GET", "datas.json", true);
request.send();
```

Comment: Perfect. Except just on little thing. `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'div.innerHTML = element.value')` The problem now is if one element is not in the page, it causes an error. How can I fix it please?