# Switch case in javascript to fill an instruction

Tags: javascript

Could you please help me with this piece of code that doesn't want to work ?

I'm trying to change the content of an element.

- If I receive `input` or `textarea`, I will apply `innerHTML`.
- If I receive `file`, I will apply `src`.

My HTML example is the following:

```
<div id="hotel_name"></div>
<div id="hotel_description"></div>
<img src="" id="logo">
```

And it's my JS code:

```
function createElements(request) {
    var elements = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    elements.datas.forEach(function (element) {

        switch(element.type) {
            case 'input':
            case 'textarea':
                type = 'innerHTML';
                break;
            case 'file':
                type = 'src';
                break;
        }

        var div = document.getElementById(element.id)||null;
        div!=null&&(div.type = element.value);
    });
}
```

The json looks like:

```
{
    "datas": [
        {
            "id": "hotel_name",
            "value": "Banana"
        },
        {
            "id": "hotel_description",
            "value": "This is a banana."
        },
        {
            "id": "logo",
            "value": "logo.png"
        },
        ...
```

But it doesn't work. I think this line `div!=null&&(div.type = element.value);` do not understand what I want.

Could you please help ?

Thanks.

Comment: var div = document.getElementById(element.id)||null; - why did you put || in this line. AND what is this linen means - div!=null&&(div.type = element.value);  ???

Comment: Can you include a part or example of the json response please.

Comment: I've update with the json I get.

Comment: @TheGuest: was a previous question here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29569541/4761115

Comment: `div!=null&&(div.type = element.value);` This line is confusing, you are checking if div is not null and before checking if div.type is declared it is assigned element.id.

Comment: I need to check if an id exists in the page.

Comment: Anyway `if(div!=null)div.type = element.value;` don't work too.

Answer (score 0):

The varible type is implicitly defined and i think you probably made an error in this : div[type] = element.value